# How should I submit an anonymous lambda that has a self reference?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

In a lot of situations we allow for C# answers to simply be an anonymous lambda with the assumption that to run it it needs to be stored in a variable.

So given that, is it acceptable to also assume that the variable have a specific name so that it can call itself?

An example using Fibonacci:

```
//Boilerplate
Func<int,int> f = ()=> {};
f=
//golfed function
    n=>n<2?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the lambda needs a specific name to work (because you're calling it recursively), then you'll have to count the declaration and definition of that name, I'm afraid. So it'll have to be something like

```
Func<int,int>f=n=>n<2?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2);
```

Not entirely sure if that requires some additional space somewhere. I'm also not sure whether the compiler would accept `var` there as the type, but in any case, you'll have to count all the code that's required to make the answer work and declare the necessary names.

Note that not *all* languages require named functions for recursion. For example, in Mathematica, you can refer to the nearest surrounding unnamed function with `#0`, which means that

```
If[#<2,1,#0[#-1]+#0[#-2]]&
```

would be a valid submission, because here a name is not required to make the function work. (That said, I think a named function would actually be shorter, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: So the interesting thing about your second paragraph is that in C# you can't use the `var` keyword for anonymous lambdas so one could argue that the typed variable is required to consider it 'working', and yes a named function would indeed by shorter in this case.

Comment: Note that the code sample here won't compile, because C# will insist you assign `f` before using it in the lambda. For example `Func<int, int> f = null; f = n => n < 2 ? 1 : f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);`

Comment: @VisualMelon Of course! So there's little use for recursive lambdas now :|

Answer (score 2):

I don't include the declaration in the byte count, however you need the function name because **it's recursive**, so the code size should be calculated on this snippet:

```
f=n=>n<2?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2);
```

Leading to **25 bytes**.

The verbose, working version is **45 bytes**:

```
Func<int,int>f=null;f=n=>n<2?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2);
```

Which means there's little use for recursive lambda functions. The `classic` version is **41 bytes**:

```
int f(int n){return n<2?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2);}
```